# Adding ajaxControlToolKit to visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ajaxcontroltoolkit

When trying to add the AjaxControlToolkit.dll file I am getting this message:
"Security Warning: This file is possibly downloaded from a network location, and it can potentially harm your computer. Only load assemblies from publisher you trust.

Do you want to load it anyway ?
"

I chose YES, and although the ajax controlls do not add to my tab.

What should I do ?

Answer (score 1):

I just download the Ajax. So you might downloading it form not trusted site. Try, ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com and you go there go to downloads and choose either the first one which is Ajax Control Toolkit 4 or whatever you need. Let me know if you need any help or if you face any thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the AjaxControlToolkit using NuGet. See the official [Codeplex page](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/) for instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a DLL does not necessary result in adding Controls to the toolbar. You can specificy in the settings dialog of the toolbar if controls from perticular assembly should be shown.